# central alignment in constraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I tried using chainStyle but didn't work. Please suggest a solution to this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO11Z.png)

I want to align these buttons centrally just like the two textviews above. I have provided the code for the '+3 points'button here.

I want to implement this using chainStyle. What should I do for that?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/points_3A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:onClick="points3"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/points_3B"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/team_a_score"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_3B"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:onClick="points3"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/points_3A"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/team_b_score" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a Guideline like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/points_3A"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
    android:text="+3 points"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/points_3B"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:text="+3 points"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any way to implement this using chainStyle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Guideline` with 50% and then bound your buttons to the guideline

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineHalf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

Your buttons will be now:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/points_3A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:onClick="points3"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guidelineHalf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/team_a_score"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_3B"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:onClick="points3"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guidelineHalf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/team_b_score" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do the entire thing

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_3A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/points_3B"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ta" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_3B"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+3 points"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/points_3A"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_2A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+2 points"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/points_2B"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points_3A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_2B"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="+2 points"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/points_2A"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points_3B" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_FA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="Free Throw"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/points_FB"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points_2A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points_FB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="Free Throw"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/points_FA"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points_2B" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ta"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="TeamA\n2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tb"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="TeamB\n2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ta"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```